What is the scriptural basis for the claim that Siva was a devotee of Vishnu?
ISKCON monks have said several times that Siva is the greatest devotee of Krishna (or Vishnu). For example, Amogh Lila Prabhu said it. However, I found the opposite claim in Siva Purana (Rudra Samhita, Sati Khanda, Chapter 2).

‘“Brahma replied, ‘O sage! Listen to everything about Sati and Shiva’s auspicious account. This is extremely divine and purifying. Among all secrets, it is the supreme secret. O sage! In earlier times, Shambhu himself narrated this to Vishnu, his noble devotee. When he was asked with great devotion, he did this for the sake of benefit to others. After this, I asked the intelligent Vishnu, Shiva’s supreme devotee. O supreme among sages! Out of his love for me, he told me in detail.

Is there any scriptural basis for the claim that Siva was a devotee of Vishnu?

Puranic literate was Sect oriented. So that like-minded people can come together and perform rituals in a focused way. Today because of media and other communication channels this has become a Shiva Vishnu campaine. Best one adheres to Itihasas and Upanishads.

This is mentioned in Srimad Bhagavatam.

ŚB 12.13.16


निम्नगानां यथा गङ्गा देवानामच्युतो यथा ।


वैष्णवानां यथा शम्भु: पुराणानामिदं तथा ॥ १६ ॥


Just as the Gaṅgā is the greatest of all rivers, Lord Acyuta the supreme among deities and Lord Śambhu [Śiva] the greatest of Vaiṣṇavas, so Śrīmad-Bhāgavatam is the greatest of all Purāṇas.


So, it is the old Saiva-Vaishnava rivalry. In their own Puranas, they made their God supreme, and made the other God as the devotee! Funny!


Lord Shiva always mediates upon Lord Vishnu -


"On being asked thus, Śaṃbhu, the servant of Hari said: “I meditate
upon the essence of the thousand names of Hari always. I perform
Japa of the seventh incarnation of Hari known by the name of Rāma and
the twenty-four manifestations as well as the good qualities of Hari."


Chapter 256, Tirtha Mahatmya, Skanda Purana.


Lord Shiva's words to Parvati -


"Everyday I adore him with penance, I eulogise him and think of
him. Viṣṇu alone is the highest one. Knowledge about him is the
means of salvation. This is the verdict of the sacred texts.
Anything other than that causes delusion."


Chapter 71, Uttara Khanda, Padma Purana.


Amogh Lila Claims According To Bhagwat Puran 12.13.16 Mahadev Is Supreme Vaishnav,
But Amogh Lila Never Mentions That Shiv Puran 2.5.2.42 Says Krishna(Vishnu) Is Supreme Shaiv.
Not Even Shiv Puran But Padma Puran 5.105 Mahavishnu Is Shiv Bhakta, Brahmavaivarta Puran 4.75.86 Bhagwan Shree Krishna Says Those Brahman Who Doesnt Worship Mahadev Who Is Worshipped By Me! Attains Narak Till Age Of 100 Brahma.
Shiv Puran 7.2.30.12-13 Mentions 11 Murtis Of Bhagwan Of Shiv The eleven Mūrtis are: Mahādeva, Śiva, Rudra, Śaṅkara, Nīlalohita, Īśāna, Vijaya, Bhīma, Devadeva, Bhavodbhava and Kapardīśa.
It Means The Shambhu Murti Of Bhagwan Shiv Can Be Supreme Vaishnav As In Ishwar Gita 7.4,5 Mahadev Himself Says I Am Shambhu Among Yogis, I Am Shankar Among Rudras.
It Means Mahadev Talks About His Avatars Murtis In Ishwar Gita, So It Is Possible That Vaishnav Shambhu Is Avatar Of Bhagwan Shiv
Jai Mata Di Jai Shiv Shankar Jai Shree Krishna
Jai Shree Hari Narayana Vishnu
Jai Shree Ram Jai Hanuman Har Har Mahadev Om Namah Shivaaya

Please format your answer properly and quote relevant verses from Puranas accordingly

I Have Mentioned Proper Source For All Only Didnt Mentioned Sloka Of Padma Puran Chapter Because Entire Chapter Mentions Mahavishnu's Bhakti For Bhagwan Shiv.

you mentioned, but you did not quote them, I have no access to them, why can't you post them here - only the slokas you quoted?

There Are Different Websites With Different Sources, But Few Websites Like Getwisdom And Wisdomlib Mentions Puranas ETC

As you have used Shiva Purana in your question, quoting this from Shiva Purana itself. Actually, this is complex, you would find instances in Puranas of Vishnu/Rama/Krishna worshipping Shiva (like Rama in Rameswara, Krishna for begetting sons) and Shiva worshipping Vishnu/Rama/Krishna as discussed below. They are great devotees of each other.
As per Shiva Purana > Rudra-saṃhitā : Satī-khaṇḍa > Chapter 24 - Satī’s test of Rāma’s divinity, Lord Shiva bowed to Lord Rama.


The great liberal-minded lord Śiva who is Pūrṇakāma (one whose ambitions are fully realised) delightfully bowed to Rāma who was wandering in the forest in the company of Lakṣmaṇa and was in need of a favour.


After this, Goddess Sati got somewhat same question as of yours and asked


How is it that Thou becomest highly delighted and behavest like a devotee on seeing the elder of the two who resembles a blue lotus (in complexion)?


Shiva answered this way:


The fair-complexioned one is the younger brother Lakṣmaṇa. He is the partial incarnation of Śeṣa. The elder one is the complete incarnation of Viṣṇu. He is called Rāma. He is incapable of being harassed.

The lord has incarnated on the Earth for our welfare and the protection of the good.” Saying thus Śiva, the lord, who causes prosperity to his votaries stopped.



But still Sati was not convinced so Shiva suggested her to test Rama's divinity herself. Sati went to Rama in the guise of Sītā but Rama immediately recognized her. On being asked why does Shiva worship Rama (or Vishnu and his incarnations), Rama told the following story:

Rāma said:—

Śiva, caused Viśvakarman to make an excellent, divine, wonderful umbrella for warding off obstacles.

With a delightful mind He called Viṣṇu from Vaikuṇṭha. O Goddess, Śiva rejoiced at the perfect devotion of Viṣṇu.

In an auspicious hour, the great lord made Viṣṇu sit on the exquisite throne and delightedly decorated him in every way.

A beautiful coronet was fixed on Viṣṇu and the auspicious holy thread was tied to his waist. He was then coronated by lord Śiva in
the Cosmic Hall.

What was His own and even non-transferable, Śiva the independent and favourably disposed to His devotees, conferred on Viṣṇu and
eulogised him.

The lord who is favourably disposed to His devotees, revealing Himself independent but subservient to the boons granted by Him, spoke
these words to Brahmā the creator of all worlds.


Lord Śiva said:—
15-16. Lord, may you all hear. From now onwards, at my bidding, this
Viṣṇu has become worthy of my respect and that of all devas. Dear one,
you too bow to him. May all the Vedas extol him at my bidding as they
extol me.
Rāma said:—

So saying, Rudra, Himself bowed to Garuḍa-bannered Viṣṇu. The bestower of boons, He who is favourably disposed to His devotees, felt
delighted by his devotion to Viṣṇu.

Then Viṣṇu was duly revered by Brahmā followed by devas, sages, Siddhas and others.

Then the delighted Lord Śiva, favourably disposed towards his devotees, bestowed great boons on Viṣṇu and the other devas.


Lord Śiva said:—

At my bidding you are now the creator, sustainer and destroyer of all the worlds. You are the bestower of virtue, wealth and love and
the chastiser of people of evil predilection.

You are the lord of the universe. You are worthy of the worship of the universe. You will be invincible in battle anywhere even against
me. You will be endowed with great strength and valour.

You take three Śaktis—will etc. conferred by me. You can have the power of exhibiting diverse sports and independence in the three
worlds.

O Viṣṇu, persons who hate you shall indeed be chastised and curbed by me with strenuous efforts. Salvation shall be given by me, O Viṣṇu,
to your devotees.




The claim is based on Srimad Bhagwatam (SB 12.13.16) where Shiva is said to be the best of Vaishnavas.
However, what we need to be very clear is that the term Vaishnava here strictly means one who adores and meditates on Vishnu. It has nothing to do with being a devotee of Vishnu in the modern sectarian sense of Vaishnavism or subscribing to any theological doctrine of Vaishnavism.
Another verse that can be found in Bhagwatam relating to the same is 4.3.23  where Shiva tells Sati that he worships Vasudeva. Vasudeva here is Krishna/Vishnu in the form of the supreme Brahmana or vice versa as is evident from the preceding verse.
Harivamsa Chapter 90 has Mahadeva's stuti to Vasudeva, adoring him as Ishwara.
By these, it is evident that Bhagwan Shiva adores and meditates on Vishnu as Prabrahman. However, what needs to be clear is also that this should not be compared to the meditation or devotion that is present among us mortals. Shiva and Vishnu are the supreme Saguna manifestations of Brahman as Ishvara.
As is the devotion of Shiva to Vishnu/Krishna when they are seen as Ishwara Swarup of Brahman, same is the devotion of Krishna/Vishnu to Shiva when he is seen as Ishwara.
Anushasana Parva (MBH, KMG CLX) is the recitation of Vasudeva Krishna to Yudhishthira where he says, "O king, listen to me as I recite to you that Sata-rudriya which I repeat; with restrained senses, every morning after rising from bed" and then sings the glories of Shankara as Ishwara.
Drona Vadha Parva (MBH, KMG, CCII) Vyasa recites to Arjuna that he has seen "seen Sankara, that First cause from which have sprung the Prajapatis".
Harivamsa (Chapter. 74) has Shri Krishna's Stuti to Rudra Mahadeva along with the mention of installation of a Shivalinga by Krishna called "Bilvodakeshwara".
In the same Itihasa, Mahabharata or Harivamsa, we have alternating adoration and stutis of Shiva to Vasudeva and Vasudeva to Shiva. The same is the case with even Rigveda where both Rudra and Vishnu are praised as supreme forms of Ishwara.
Rigveda 1.156.2, “He who presents (offerings) to Viṣṇu, the ancient, the creator, the recent, the self-born; he who celebrates the great birth of that mighty one; he verily possessed of abundance, attains (the station) that is to be sought (by all).”
Rigveda 2.33.9, "(Firm) with strong limbs, assuming many forms fierce, and tawny-coloured, he shines with brilliant golden ornaments; vigour is inseparable from Rudra, the supreme ruler and lord of this world.” In the next verse, 2.33.10 Rudra is said to be the preserver of the world.
Conclusion: Both Shiva and Krishna/Vishnu being Ishvara in the complete sense and knower of Parabrahman as well as of each other's Ishwaratva, glorify, adore and meditate on each other. The same with Rishis who, on seeing both as supreme Ishwara and forms of the same Parabrahman (even saying form of Parabrahman is fallacy since there is no difference between them and Parabrahman yet, for simplicity..), sing praises of both as supreme. There is neither conflict nor contradiction here.
Unless ofcourse you want to go out on the quest to show one supreme over the other, which will lead to only headache and choicest of contorted interpretations.
